# Change div order to suite responsive viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm using the script below to change the order of two divs - my document's HTML has the div class "imagepanel ip-middle" preceding the div class "bgimagescale image2". When viewing on a viewport smaller than 768px wide - I want the divs reversed. The script below does not reverse the divs on page load. Only on resize - as I guess the script indicates!: .bind("resize", listenWidth). I have been unable to locate the right way to change the order of the divs using jquery on page load as well as resize. Many thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).load($(window).bind("resize", listenWidth));

function listenWidth( e ) {
    if($(window).width()<767)
    {
        $("div.imagepanel.ip-middle").remove().insertAfter($("div.bgimagescale.image2"));
    } else {
        $("div.imagepanel.ip-middle").remove().insertBefore($("div.bgimagescale.image2"));
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `load` and `resize` together, something like this:

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see your html too to give you precise advice, but actually you don't need any js for this at all. Just use pure css and a little trick with floating. First set both divs to float left.

```css
div{
  float:left;
  clear:both;
  }
```

and on media change, just change the float to "right" - right float reverses the order of elements.

```css
@media (max-width < 767px){
  div{ float:right }
  }
```

That's all :)